# Bug in the reputation tab of my own profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-tab

When looking through the reputation tab of your own profile, there are bars for each day, and you click on that bar to get a list of all the reputation changes to your account on that day.

However, mine seems to be bugged. When I click on a bar, it shows me the reputation changes for the previous day. See the picture (from my profile on the main site, mathematics.SE):

[image]

I have clicked on the bar representing yesterday, where I got $10$ reputation. However, the list below the graph shows the reputation changes of the day before, where I got $205$ reputation.

This means that if one day I get no reputation (such as Nov 13 in the picture), then I cannot get the details of the day before (Nov 12). There is no way for me to make that page show me what I did to get reputation on November 12.

Techincal details: I run Win7 professional service pack 1 with Chrome 46 at the moment, but the problem has persisted for some time and is reproducibe in Firefox 42.0 and Internet Explorer 11.0

Comment: I experience the same problem.

Comment: Possibly related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269831/date-discrepancies-in-the-25k-site-analytics).

Comment: I also have the same problem with OS X.